# What is the difference between these development, implementation, construction

Tags: software-design

What is the difference between these concepts:

1. development of code
2. implementation of code
3. construct a code

and are these concepts correct to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all the phases involved in order to build a software basically the difference in above one of the phases which you have asked is it starts from designing is what you visually think as a plan then you need to develop it i.e. by writing the code which is core to make your software as functional and finally implementation i.e. deployment of your code to run it on a platform.